# Getting object properties that start with a number

Tags: javascript

I've got an object where one of the properties starts with a number. I've read that this was allowed, but I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

```
var stats = {"LOAD_AVG":{"1_MIN":0.08,"5_MIN":0.08,"15_MIN":0.08},"COUNTS":{"TOTAL":888,"RUNNING":1,"SLEEPING":887,"STOPPED":0,"ZOMBIE":0},"CPU":{"USER_CPU_TIME":8.9,"SYSTEM_CPU_TIME":2.4,"NICE_CPU_TIME":0,"IO_WAIT_TIME":1,"HARD_TIME":0,"SOFT_TIME":0.1,"STEAL_TIME":0},"MEMORY":{"PHYSICAL":{"TOTAL":"3921.98mb","IN_USE":"3682.652mb (93.9%)","AVAILABLE":"239.328mb (6.1%)","BUFFERS":"266.492mb (6.8%)"},"SWAP":{"TOTAL":"4194.296mb","IN_USE":"64.264mb (1.5%)","AVAILABLE":"4130.032mb (98.5%)","CACHE":"1191.328mb (28.4%)"}}};

//works fine
window.alert(stats.COUNTS.TOTAL);

//doesn't work
window.alert(stats.LOAD_AVG.1_MIN);
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tbLua5de/1/)

How can I access the properties that begin with a number without rewriting the PHP that generated it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, really.  It's just the way Javascript objects work, whether initialized from a literal (which is basically the definition of JSON) or not.  `foo.bar` is just a shortcut for `foo["bar"]` that works when the key string happens to make a valid Javascript identifier.

Comment: @MarkReed While it is correct that the OP is not accessing a JSON object, if the JSON did not have a property starting with a number, the problem wouldn't exist :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bracket access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for properties that aren't valid JavaScript identifiers, that goes for property names with spaces or other language symbols like `+`, `*`

```
window.alert(stats.LOAD_AVG["1_MIN"]);
```

You can use bracket access anywhere really

```
window.alert(stats["COUNTS"]["TOTAL"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Will accespt shortly.