# openweather rain json not show

Tags: jquery, html, json, openweathermap

```
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = '{"coord":{"lon":108.27,"lat":-7.68},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":26.97,"pressure":1010.86,"humidity":100,"temp_min":26.97,"temp_max":26.97,"sea_level":1021.57,"grnd_level":1010.86},"wind":{"speed":1.61,"deg":232.009},"rain":{"3h":1.88},"clouds":{"all":56},"dt":1474443506,"sys":{"message":0.1676,"country":"ID","sunrise":1474411011,"sunset":1474454577},"id":8044852,"name":"Bojongsari","cod":200}';

var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.rain.3h 
</script>

</body>
```

why **obj.rain.3h** not showing while the other success like obj.clouds.all

Comment: instead of dot way use `[]` like `data['rain']['3h']`

Comment: i can't edit the json because i got it from the openweather API direct link

Comment: instead of using `obj.rain.3h` use `data['rain']['3h']`

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pkmsm88r/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting object properties that start with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494991/getting-object-properties-that-start-with-a-number)

Comment: @guraido Thanks it works

Comment: @AgungChrisnaNugroho happy to help mate :)